# Pygame I can move an image once but don't know how to move it twice

Tags: python, pygame

I have a box that i want to move in increments, i know how to move it by an increment but only once. I don't how i'd do this multiple times. anyone got any ideas?
The box:

```
highlight = pygame.draw.rect(window, (darkYellow),(30, 300, 130, 40),0)
```

Moving the box (this is to move it once)

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_RIGHT:
            highlight = pygame.draw.rect(window, (darkYellow),(260, 300, 130, 40),0)
            difficultyText = myFont.render("Difficulty", 1, red)
            window.blit(difficultyText, (260, 300))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Takes any key input when i only want it to activate when the key "ARROW DOWN" is pushed

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_DOWN:
            window.blit(arrowImg, (5,400))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

You are drawing, rendering text and bliting in your event loop. You should move them out of the loop body.

It seems that you want to have a cursor that will change its position with the right arrow key.

To do this have a variable that will tell you where your cursor is.

Then your draw statement will look like this:

```
pygame.draw.rect(window, (darkYellow),(30+cursorPos*230, 300, 130, 40),0)
```

EDIT:

As for why `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.K_DOWN` is true for all KEY_DOWN events, is because it can be translated to `(event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN) and pygame.K_DOWN`.

Since pygame.K_DOWN is a non zero value, it is true when evaluated as a boolean value.
To fix this you want to do something like this:

```
event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN
```

Comment: why did you do 30 + cursor * 230?

Comment: Also the reason i'm drawing it all in the loop is bewcause i want it to refresh the page

Comment: Also, i'm drawing the text in the loop because of the way blitting works in PyGame. When the rect moves, it layers over the text so i re draw the text

Comment: @user3166976 you are drawing only when the user pressed the K_RIGHT.
You should draw even when the user is not pressing anything. As for the equation, I took your two rectangle positions and made this. When `cursorPos` is 1, it will be in the second position, when it is 0, it will be int the first one.

Comment: Thanks i fixed some stuff. Also have you got any idea why this takes any input when i only want it to take input down?